# Usage of AWS Lake Formation with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-lake-formation

I want to set up an additional security layer on top of my S3 / Glue Data Lake
using Lake Formation. I want to do as much as possible via Infrastructure as Code, so naturally I looked into the documentation of the [CloudFormation implementation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lakeformation-datalakesettings.html) of Lake Formation which is currently, frankly speaking, very useless.

I have a simple use case: **Granting admin permission to one IAM-User on one bucket**.
Can someone help me out with an example or anything similar?

Comment: Did you find any template or example since you posted your question?

Comment: I've added an answer with my current template.

Answer (score 3):

**This is what I found out:**

Setting a data lake location and granting data permissions to your data bases is currently possible. Unfortunately it seems like `CloudFormation` doesn't support `Data locations` yet. You will have to grant your `IAM Role` access to the `S3 Bucket` by hand in the AWS Console under `Lake Formation -> Data locations`. I will update the answer as soon as `CloudFormation` supports more.

**This is the template that we are using at the moment:**

```
DataBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      AccessControl: Private
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: AES256
      VersioningConfiguration:
        Status: Enabled
      LifecycleConfiguration:
        Rules:
          - Id: InfrequentAccessRule
            Status: Enabled
            Transitions:
              - TransitionInDays: 30
                StorageClass: INTELLIGENT_TIERING

GlueDatabase:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Database
    Properties:
      CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
      DatabaseInput:
        Name: !FindInMap [Environment, !Ref Environment, GlueDatabaseName]
        Description: !Sub Glue Database ${Environment}

GlueDataAccessRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSGlueServiceRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Sid: ''
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: glue.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: AccessDataBucketPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - glue:*
                  - lakeformation:*
                Resource: '*'
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - s3:GetObject
                  - s3:PutObject
                  - s3:ListBucket
                  - s3:DeleteObject
                Resource:
                  - !Sub ${DataBucket.Arn}
                  - !Sub ${DataBucket.Arn}/*

 DataBucketLakeFormation:
    Type: AWS::LakeFormation::Resource
    Properties:
      ResourceArn: !GetAtt DataBucket.Arn
      UseServiceLinkedRole: true

DataLakeFormationPermission:
    Type: AWS::LakeFormation::Permissions
    Properties:
      DataLakePrincipal:
        DataLakePrincipalIdentifier: !GetAtt GlueDataAccessRole.Arn
      Permissions:
        - ALL
      Resource:
        DatabaseResource:
          Name: !Ref GlueDatabase
        DataLocationResource:
          S3Resource: !Ref DataBucket
```

Comment: Do you know if cloudformation supports this now?

Comment: I am not using LakeFormation anymore, but I don't think so.